# How to achieve selection of radio element on click of label

Tags: html, css

I have this situation

```
<input type="radio">
<span class="theLabel">Radio label</span>
```

When the user clicks on `span.theLabel` the click event should be transferred to the radio element, just like if it was a `<label>` element. Problem is, I need to be a span, and I need to do this with css only, no javascript involved. Is it possible?

Comment: short answer: you cannot

Comment: will it be okay if you wrap the `<span>` with `<label for="#">` ? Then you can achieve what you want, otherwise i cannot think of another way to do this without using javascript.

Comment: Agree with PR7, wrap input inside the label: ```<label class="theLabel"><input type="radio"></label>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible..

you have to just add a opening and closing tag of label. look at below HTML.

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="theLabel">Label text</span>
</label>
```